# OpenCvSharp memory leak

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am using OpenCvSharp for video capturing and blending. I have memory leak problem. Although I disposed everything but I observed constantly increasing memory. Do you have any suggestion about this problem. Thank you so much.

```
while (videoStreamFlag)
            {
                if(startFlag)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        capture2.Read(image2);
                        capture.Read(image);

                        if (image.Empty() || image2.Empty())
                        {
                            videoStreamFlag = false;
                            break;
                        }

                        if (bitimg != null)
                            bitimg.Dispose();
                        bitimg = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, ((image.Width * 3 + 3) / 4) * 4, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, image.Data);

                        if (result != null)
                            result.Dispose();
                        result = new Bitmap(bitimg.Width, bitimg.Height);

                        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
                        {
                            g.DrawImageUnscaled(bitimg, 0, 0);

                            if (bitimg != null)
                                bitimg.Dispose();
                            bitimg = new Bitmap(image2.Width, image2.Height, ((image2.Width * 3 + 3) / 4) * 4, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, image2.Data);
                            bitimg = SetImageOpacity(bitimg, Opacity / 100f);
                            g.DrawImageUnscaled(bitimg, 0, 0);


                            if (pictureBox.Image != null)
                                panel.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () { pictureBox.Image.Dispose(); }));

                            Thread.Sleep(1);
                            pictureBox.Image = result;

                            Thread.Sleep(1);
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("[ERROR!!!]VideoBlending Error...{0}", ex.Message);
                        videoStreamFlag = false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAT71.png)

Comment: `panel.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () { result.Dispose(); })); result = new Bitmap(bitimg.Width, bitimg.Height);` obviously doesn't make sens (and is the cause of memory leak) because you always call dispose to current  `result` ... by current I mean at the time of calling `result.Dispose()` not at the time of `panel.Invoke` **and no, this is not the same time**

Comment: @Selvin I was using `result.Dispose()` at first, but I'm facing the same problem.